# php dynamic populating the drop down list based on the selected value of first list

Tags: php, sql

Before I start I am aware that mysql is depreciated but my supervisor wants me to use it for this project.

Currently have two tables in a database called "users_db". Both tables contain one column.

The table labelled "year_of_study" contains the column "year_name".
The table is populated as follows:

The year_name are "Primary School", "Junior Cycle", "Senior Cycle".

The table labelled "school" contains the column "name_school".
The table is populated as follows:

The name_school are "Goldsmith Hall", "Marian College", "Ringsend", "St.Andrew's"

When user selects "Primary School" from the first drop down I want the second drop down to populate with only "Goldsmith Hall" and "Marian College". And when the user selects "Junior Cycle" or "Senior Cycle" I want the second drop down to populate with only "Ringsend" and "St.Andrew's".

I know that I will probably need an AJAX onchange or javascript? But my problem is that I have gone through tutorials without much luck

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me

```
<br>
 <?php
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_select_db("users_db");
   $query = "SELECT DISTINCT year_name FROM year";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
  ?>


<label for="year_of_study">Year of study</label>
  <select name="year_of_study" id="year_of_study">
  <option value="null" selected>--Select One--</option>

  <?php
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {      

  echo "<option value=\"".mysql_real_escape_string($row['year_of_study'])."\">".$row["year_of_study"]."</option>";

  }
  ?>

   </select>

  <br>

  <?php
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_select_db("users_db");
   $query = "SELECT DISTINCT name_school FROM school";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
  ?>


<label for="student_availability">Availability</label>
  <select name="student_availability" id="student_availability">
  <option value="null" selected>--Select One--</option>

  <?php
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {      

  echo "<option value=\"".mysql_real_escape_string($row['name_school'])."\">".$row["name_school"]."</option>";

  }
  ?>

   </select>

  <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably best implementing some sort of web service and then doing some JavaScript in this situation. There's definitely no way to do it dynamically with a server-side language like PHP - you've got to use JavaScript or Dart to perform client-side actions. Seen as you're using PHP you could use [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com) to give you a bit of a RESTful API.

After you've installed Slim do:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/school/:student_availability', function ($student_availability) {
    // do your query here and echo the results in JSON format
});
$app->run();
```

Then in jQuery on the "student_availability" selection change you can do:

```
$.getJSON("<yoururl>/school/" + $('#student_availability').val, function(result) {
    // you might want to clear it here to stop it becoming overpopulated
    $.each(result, function() {
        $('#student_availability').append($("<option/>").val(result.school_id).text(result.name_school));
    });
});
```

Not a complete answer but hopefully a point in the right direction. I'd also highly recommend looking into some sort of JavaScript web application framework, here are a couple to have a read about if you're interested in client-rich web apps:

- [Backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org): apps like [Trello](http://trello.com) are built using this.
- [AngularJs](http://angularjs.org): Google's own JS framework. I believe they use it for their cloud apps control panel.
- [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com): less adoption than the previous two but claims to be "more productive out of the box" so perhaps less of a learning curve.

If these do interest you then definitely look at [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) to make a RESTful API.

All the best.